# How to assign name of type object of object as variable using TypeScript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How I can assign name of the object as a variable `$var1` using TypeScript

```
const $var1 = 'email';
data = [{
          name: 'John',
          $var1: 22 
       }];
```

Comment: `data = [{  name: 'John', email: 22 }];` - you want this?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want, but I want email as a variable

Comment: Do you want change $var1 from 'email' to 'John'

Comment: `data = [{name: 'John',[$var1]: 22 }];`

Comment: Thanks all, its working as @Mohammadreza Mirhajianmoghadam answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use JS [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

```
const $var1 = 'email';
data = [{
          name: 'John',
          [$var1]: 22 
       }];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert variable as key using `Object[variable]` as follows.

```js
const $var1 = 'email';

// -- First Way
const data = [{
  name: 'John',
}];
data[0][$var1] = 22;
console.log(data);

// -- Second Way
const result2 = [{
  name: 'John',
  [$var1]: 22
}];
console.log(result2);
```